# Doing multiple joins in a query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fairly new to MySQL and I am having some trouble figuring this out.

I have two tables called `doctors` and `doctor_tags`

Fields for `doctors`: `doctor_id`, `doctor_name`

Fields for `doctor_tags`: `id`, `doctor_id`, `tag_name`

Now for a specific `doctor_id` I need to find related doctors. Doctors are related if they have the same `tag_name`. Once I find this relation I need to get `doctor_name` of all these doctors back.

I am almost completely lost I've got this far (I am sure it's wrong)

`SELECT doctors.doctor_name, doctors.doctor_id FROM doctors INNER JOIN doctors_tags ON doctors.doctor_id = doctors_tags.doctor_id ...`

I konw this query is pretty useless but I know we need an some type of join.

For whoever is kind enough to comeup with some sort of query, I would be *very thankful if you could explain each part* of it in the process. Thanks :)

EDIT: Part 2

If lets say we introduce another table that has an N:N relationship between doctor_id and tag_id

Table fields
`doctor_tags_joins`: `doctor_id`,`tag_id`

and so the fields for the tag table change to

`doctors_tags`: `tag_id`, `tag_name` and so on...

how can we do the same thing with this additional table included into the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables twice:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT d1.doctor_id, d2.doctor_name
FROM doctors AS d1
-- Get first doctor's tags
JOIN doctor_tags AS dt1 ON d1.doctor_id = dt1.doctor_id
-- Get all the other doctor_tags rows with the same tags
JOIN doctor_tags AS dt2 ON dt1.tag_name = dt2.tag_name 
    -- Don't list doctors as related to themselves
    AND dt1.doctor_id != dt2.doctor_id
-- Get those doctors' names
JOIN doctors AS d2 ON dt2.doctor_id = d2.doctor_id
ORDER BY d1.doctor_id, d2.doctor_name
```

I use `DISTINCT` so we don't get multiple rows for the same doctors if they have multiple tags in common.

If you're just looking up doctors related to a specific doctor, rather than all doctors, the query becomes:

```
SELECT doctor_name
FROM doctor_tags AS dt1
JOIN doctor_tags AS dt2 ON dt1.tag_name = dt2.tag_name AND dt1.doctor_id != dt2.doctor_id
JOIN doctors AS d2 ON dt2.doctor_id = d2.doctor_id
WHERE dt1.doctor_id = :doctor_id
```

where `:doctor_id` is a placeholder for the given doctor. You don't need the first `doctor` table because you're not using any information from that table.

If you want to get all the related doctor names on one line, use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT d1.doctor_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d2.doctor_name) AS related_doctors
FROM doctors AS d1
JOIN doctor_tags AS dt1 ON d1.doctor_id = dt1.doctor_id
JOIN doctor_tags AS dt2 ON dt1.tag_name = dt2.tag_name AND dt1.doctor_id != dt2.doctor_id
JOIN doctors AS d2 ON dt2.doctor_id = d2.doctor_id
GROUP BY d1.doctor_id
```

For your second question, the queries are the same, except you use `doctor_tags_join` instead of `doctor_tags`. Since you're not showing the tag names in the results, the `doctor_tags` table is irrelevant.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.doctor_id, d2.doctor_name
FROM doctors AS d1
JOIN doctor_tags_join AS dt1 ON d1.doctor_id = dt1.doctor_id
JOIN doctor_tags_join AS dt2 ON dt1.tag_id = dt2.tag_id 
    AND dt1.doctor_id != dt2.doctor_id
JOIN doctors AS d2 ON dt2.doctor_id = d2.doctor_id
ORDER BY d1.doctor_id, d2.doctor_name
```

Comment: Would a subquery solution be slower than a triple join? eg. `SELECT doctors.doctor_name
FROM doctors
INNER JOIN doctor_tags ON doctor_tags.doctor_id = doctors.doctor_id
WHERE doctor_tags.tag_name IN ( SELECT tag_name FROM doctor_tags WHERE doctor_id = '%' )`

Comment: They might be treated the same, check what EXPLAIN says.

Comment: Ok. I just ask this because it seems a little more... intuitive with the subquery.

Comment: MySQL doesn't always optimize `IN (SELECT...)` very well, so I try to avoid it.

Comment: This is great, just wondering `JOIN` you used is that an `INNER JOIN` or some other sort of join?

Comment: `JOIN` is implicitly the same as an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @user1952811 I've added an answer to your second question.

Comment: Great, @Barmar I was wondering if I am getting the doctor_id from somewhere else and I want to find doctors related to that doctor_id. I would simply replace the third line's `d1.doctor_id` with my own `doctor_id` correct?

Comment: I've added that query to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.doctor_id, r.doctor_name
FROM doctors d
    INNER JOIN doctor_tags dt_d
        ON d.doctor_id = dt_d.doctor_id
    INNER JOIN doctor_tags dt_r
        ON dt_d.tag_name = dt_r.tag_name
    INNER JOIN doctors r
        ON dt_r.doctor_id = r.doctor_id
WHERE d.doctor_id = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can archieve this by using sub-queries. A subquery is just a query inside another query. Here's how it can be constructed step by step

First you want the tag_name that your specified doctor_id has, right? That is:

```
select tag_name from doctors_tags where doctor_id='(your doctor_id)'
```

To get all the doctors with the same tag_name

```
SELECT doctor_id 
FROM doctors_tags 
WHERE tag_name in(
 SELECT tag_name FROM doctors_tags 
 WHERE doctor_id='(your doctor_id)' 
)
```

and the final query, obtaining the names would be:

```
select doctors.doctor_name, doctors.doctor_id 
from doctors, doctors_tags 
where doctors_tags.tag_name in(
  SELECT tag_name FROM doctors_tags 
  WHERE doctor_id='(your doctor_id)' 
)
and doctors.doctor_id = doctors_tags.doctor_id;
```

hope it helps

### edit

after including your doctor_tags_joins table, the thing looks like this

```
select doctors.doctor_name, doctors.doctor_id
from doctors, doctors_tags, doctors_tags_joins
where doctors_tags.tag_name in
(
    select tag_name 
    from doctors_tags, doctors_tags_joins
    where doctors_tags_joins.doctor_id=(your id)
    and doctors_tags.tag_id=doctors_tags_joins.tag_id
)
and doctor_tags_joins.tag_id=doctors_tags.tag_id
and doctors.doctor_id=doctors_tags.doctor_id;
```